# InDesign data merge—"remove blank lines" resulting in extra characters

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using data merge to import two variables per line, and have checked the "Remove blank lines for empty fields" box. The result is a wealth of extra characters that I can't remove using find-and-replace. Of the 24 lines of variables, typically only three contain text, so the other 21 should be empty lines and be deleted by the "Remove blank lines" option.

Attempting to paste these characters into the "find and replace" field, I see

```
^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I used to get files from a customer with these and always wondered where they came from. We used find and replaced them with nothing to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a regular text find/change.
In the Find What field, type < FEFF > (but delete the spaces before and after those angle brackets – the Stack Overflow editor seems to delete this if there are no spaces).
In the Change To, leave blank, and click change all.